# Crash on startup after intalling Roller Coaster Tycoon in Wine in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: crash, ubuntu-11.04, wine

After a seemingly successful install of Roller Coaster Tycoon (the super old one, from the old disk I had from my family's first PC) using Wine 1.2.2 (and Wine 1.3.15) on Ubuntu 11.04, the program will not launch and nothing appears in the command terminal when I attempt to launch it. The game's initial menu does appear, from which I select to play the game, then it disappears and nothing happens.

I thought it might be DirectX because some other forums suggested this, but I installed DirectX 9 under Wine and during the Roller Coaster Tycoon install, it said that the version of DirectX was fine.

Can anyone help me understand why this refuses to launch in Wine or even just how to get more information when I try to launch it?

Comment: I've already exhaustively checked the WineHQ message boards and they do not provide any useful advice.

Comment: Have you tried launching it from a shell window to get at the debug output?

Comment: Yes, whether I launch it from a shell or Linux terminal or from the drop down menus, in all cases it launches the initial menu, I click to play the game, it acts like it's loading for a few seconds, and then just quits with absolutely no feedback in the shell or terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Wine. Wine changes very rapidly. Programs that work with one version of Wine may not work in a later version. Then they get fixed in an even later version.

Try updating wine. There is an [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ppa) maintained by the Wine developers that is kept up to date. You will need to install the wine1.3 package instead of just upgrading since you are using the wine1.2 package.

Comment: When I do `sudo apt-get install wine` it says wine is already at the newest version. Do I really need to get a dev version to make the game run? Lots of people report RTC working in Wine going back several years. It doesn't make sense to me that the difference between wine 1.2.2 and wine 1.3 would matter here. All the same, I'll give it a try.

Comment: The PPA does not have dev versions of wine. It has the stable versions of Wine that have been released since the last Ubuntu release. Ubuntu updates do not give you the latest stable version of most software.

Comment: After manually updating to wine 1.3.15, the exact same behavior is replicated. Thanks for the try, though.

Answer (score 0):

On the [Wine App DB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=13611&iTestingId=64428), someone recommended a [patch](http://tinyurl.com/cc3zm7u) for Rollercoaster Tycoon that is supposed to help with startup issues.

Maybe RollerCoaster Tycoon does not like the version of Windows you are emulating. Run `winecfg` and change the "Windows Version" setting on the "Applications" tab to the version of Windows the game was released for. You should be able to set this option for RollerCoaster Tycoon only.

Comment: I installed that patch, but the same behavior is still replicated. The main menu launches, but if I click to play, it disappears and there is no error message of any kind. Thanks for the link.